# json_encode в opencart

Tags: php, json, opencart

Добрый вечер!

Скажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я понимаю:

```
$this->response->setOutput
```

а именно `setOutput` это функция? Если да, то где она описывается в opencart? В интернете не нашел, в файлах opencart не нашел (возможно плохо искал).

И вот, что еще интересует:

```
$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
```

данная строчка аналогична строчке `exit(json_encode($json));` ?

`exit(json_encode($json));` - я использую в самописном движке, поэтому хочется понять:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: `setOutput` есть метод класса **Response** возлежащего по адресу `сайт/library/response.php.

> Вообще почти всё что $this-> и не из текущего класса - из
>   сайт/library/

2: Метод отвечает за передачу данных (что и куда):

```
Это определение файла представления карты товара в контроллере и передача "в него" массива $data с данными товара.

if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product.tpl')) {
    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product.tpl', $data));
} else {
    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/product/product.tpl', $data));
}

Это окончание метода autocomplete(), который реагирует на ввод в инпуте символов и возвращает значения для подстановки.

$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
```

В первом случае он отрабатывает как маршрутизатор, обозначая какой файл представления выбрать для рендера вызванного роута и передачи в него данных. Во втором случае он работает как return метода(функции), отдавая данные в уже отрисованный файл представления.

Comment: Т.е. строка `$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));` по сути анологична - `return json_encode($json);`

Comment: да, я из спортивного интереса менял на return, возврат одинаков. просто этот метод шире функционально и ещё работает как роутер в контроллерах опенкарта в методах index.

Comment: не только в index, конечно, но это самый показательный пример.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как по другому записать без ООП: `$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');`.

Comment: не могу понять как внедрить к себе в самописный движок этот кусочек и куда его посылать)

Comment: очень такой широкий вопрос. ответ на это найдёте только изучая предмет. тут вам помогут, если у вас конкретная проблема с кодом. Вы можете открыть топик посвящённый разработке движка на мете. Такие общие вопросы - это туда. Если мой ответ был полезен, отметьте его как принятый.